# Ruby - sort array of hashes values (string) based on array order

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of hashes in the format shown below and I am attempting to sort the `:book` key of the hash based on a separate array.  The order is not alphabetical and for my use case it cannot be alphabetical.

I need to sort based on the following array:

```
array = ['Matthew', 'Mark', 'Acts', '1John']
```

Note that I've seen several solutions that leverage `Array#index` (such as [Sorting an Array of hashes based on an Array of sorted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392328/sorting-an-array-of-hashes-based-on-an-array-of-sorted-values)) to perform a custom sort but that will not work with strings.

I've tried various combinations of sorting with `Array#sort` and `Array#sort_by` but they don't seem to accept a custom order.  What am I missing?  Thank you in advance for your help!

**Array of Hashes**

```
[{:book=>"Matthew",
  :chapter=>"4",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"Matthew",
  :chapter=>"22",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"Mark",
  :chapter=>"6",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"1John",
  :chapter=>"1",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"1John",
  :chapter=>"1",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"Acts",
  :chapter=>"9",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"Acts",
  :chapter=>"17",
  :section=>"new_testament"}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `sort_by` with `index`

```
arr = [{a: 1}, {a: 3}, {a: 2}] 

order = [2,1,3]  

arr.sort_by { |elem| order.index(elem[:a]) }                                           
# => [{:a=>2}, {:a=>1}, {:a=>3}]
```

You can make it slightly faster by indexing the list of elements you want to order by:

```
order_with_index = order.each.with_object.with_index({}) do |(elem, memo), idx|
  memo[elem] = idx
end
```

then instead of `order.index(<val>)` use `order_with_index[<val>]`

Comment: Ah this one is better than my solution as `sort_by` is expensive

Comment: Max, thank you so much for the quick reply! I'll try this out.  I didn't think index could be used to compare string order.  This is very elegant--really appreciate your time.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKale, `sort_by` is cheap, not expensive. That's because the construction of a hash that maps elements to the sorting criterion is done only once, prior to  the sorting operation. By contrast, with `<=>` indices must be calculated twice for each pairwise comparison, which is much slower than performing two hash lookups.

Comment: Ah Thanks @CarySwoveland! I read https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by which mentions it being expensive 

"The current implementation of sort_by generates an array of tuples containing the original collection element and the mapped value. This makes sort_by fairly expensive when the keysets are simple."

Comment: @ChaitanyaKale, I'm amazed that `sort_by` uses an array of two-element arrays. I just assumed it would be a hash for fast lookups. Even so, `sort_by` is much faster than `sort` in many situations.

Comment: Max (et al), I am getting `comparison of Array with Array failed (ArgumentError)` when using `order.index(a[:name]) <=> order.index(b[:name]` against my real data in my app (similar to the sample data I provided).  I've been trying to diagnose it for about 2 hours and can't seem to find a pattern.  When a remove certain hashes in the array, it doesn't happen but those hashes don't appear to be different than any of the others.  Do you by chance know what would cause this?  Does your solution deal with values in my data that don't match any in the array?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't recall offhand how to reproduce this error, though I've definitely encountered it as well. Personally how I'd debug it is to install a debugger like `byebug`, then inside the sort block, use something like `byebug unless [a[:name], b[:name]].all? { |x| x.is_a? String }` to set a conditional breakpoint. At that point, you could inspect your values at runtime and determine how to proceed. You may have to put in nil checks and default values.

Comment: Thanks Max!  I found the issue--I had two names for the same book (aliases) in my data.  One was missing from the array.

Comment: This is way too complicated, you only need to sort when you don't know the order yet. Here, the order is known, it's only that the data structure is not adapted.

Comment: @VincentFourmond i'm not really clear what you mean. If you have a simpler way, maybe make another answer?

Answer (score 4):

Since you know the desired order there's no need to sort the array. Here's one way you could do that. (I've called your array of hashes `bible`.)

```
bible.group_by { |h| h[:book] }.values_at(*array).flatten
  #=> [{:book=>"Matthew", :chapter=>"4", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #    {:book=>"Matthew", :chapter=>"22", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #    {:book=>"Mark", :chapter=>"6", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #    {:book=>"Acts", :chapter=>"9", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #    {:book=>"Acts", :chapter=>"17", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #    {:book=>"1John", :chapter=>"1", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #    {:book=>"1John", :chapter=>"1", :section=>"new_testament"}]
```

Since [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) each require just one pass through the array `bible` this may be faster than sorting when `bible` is large.

Here are the steps.

```
h = bible.group_by { |h| h[:book] }
  #=> {"Matthew"=>[{:book=>"Matthew", :chapter=>"4", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #                {:book=>"Matthew", :chapter=>"22", :section=>"new_testament"}],
  #    "Mark"   =>[{:book=>"Mark", :chapter=>"6", :section=>"new_testament"}],
  #    "1John"  =>[{:book=>"1John", :chapter=>"1", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #                {:book=>"1John", :chapter=>"1", :section=>"new_testament"}],
  #    "Acts"   =>[{:book=>"Acts", :chapter=>"9", :section=>"new_testament"}, 
  #                {:book=>"Acts", :chapter=>"17", :section=>"new_testament"}]
  #   } 

a = h.values_at(*array)
  #=> h.values_at('Matthew', 'Mark', 'Acts', '1John')
  #=> [[{:book=>"Matthew", :chapter=>"4", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #     {:book=>"Matthew", :chapter=>"22", :section=>"new_testament"}],
  #    [{:book=>"Mark", :chapter=>"6", :section=>"new_testament"}],
  #    [{:book=>"Acts", :chapter=>"9", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #     {:book=>"Acts", :chapter=>"17", :section=>"new_testament"}],
  #    [{:book=>"1John", :chapter=>"1", :section=>"new_testament"},
  #     {:book=>"1John", :chapter=>"1", :section=>"new_testament"}]]
```

Lastly, `a.flatten` returns the array shown earlier.

Let's do a benchmark.

```
require 'fruity'

@bible = [
  {:book=>"Matthew",
   :chapter=>"4",
   :section=>"new_testament"},
  {:book=>"Matthew",
   :chapter=>"22",
   :section=>"new_testament"},
  {:book=>"Mark",
   :chapter=>"6",
   :section=>"new_testament"},
  {:book=>"1John",
   :chapter=>"1",
   :section=>"new_testament"},
  {:book=>"1John",
   :chapter=>"1",
   :section=>"new_testament"},
  {:book=>"Acts",
   :chapter=>"9",
   :section=>"new_testament"},
  {:book=>"Acts",
   :chapter=>"17",
   :section=>"new_testament"}]

@order = ['Matthew', 'Mark', 'Acts', '1John']
```

```
def bench_em(n)
  arr = (@bible*((n/@bible.size.to_f).ceil))[0,n].shuffle
  puts "arr contains #{n} elements"
  compare do 
    _sort       { arr.sort { |h1,h2| @order.index(h1[:book]) <=>
                  @order.index(h2[:book]) }.size }
    _sort_by    { arr.sort_by { |h| @order.find_index(h[:book]) }.size }
    _sort_by_with_hash {ord=@order.each.with_index.to_h;
                        arr.sort_by {|b| ord[b[:book]]}.size}    
    _values_at  { arr.group_by { |h| h[:book] }.values_at(*@order).flatten.size }
  end
end
```

@maxpleaner, @ChaitanyaKale and @Michael Kohl contributed `_sort`, `_sort_by`, and `sort_by_with_hash`, respectively.

```
bench_em    100
arr contains 100 elements
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_sort_by is similar to _sort_by_with_hash
_sort_by_with_hash is similar to _values_at
_values_at is faster than _sort by 2x ± 1.0

bench_em  1_000
arr contains 1000 elements
Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_sort_by_with_hash is similar to _values_at
_values_at is similar to _sort_by
_sort_by is faster than _sort by 2x ± 0.1

bench_em 10_000
arr contains 10000 elements
Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
_values_at is faster than _sort_by_with_hash by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
_sort_by_with_hash is faster than _sort_by by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
_sort_by is faster than _sort by 2x ± 0.1

bench_em 100_000
arr contains 100000 elements
Running each test once. Test will take about 3 seconds.
_values_at is similar to _sort_by_with_hash
_sort_by_with_hash is similar to _sort_by
_sort_by is faster than _sort by 2x ± 0.1
```

Here's a second run.

```
bench_em    100
arr contains 100 elements
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_sort_by_with_hash is similar to _values_at
_values_at is similar to _sort_by
_sort_by is faster than _sort by 2x ± 0.1

bench_em  1_000
arr contains 1000 elements
Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_values_at is faster than _sort_by_with_hash by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
_sort_by_with_hash is similar to _sort_by
_sort_by is faster than _sort by 2.2x ± 0.1

bench_em 10_000
arr contains 10000 elements
Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
_values_at is similar to _sort_by_with_hash
_sort_by_with_hash is similar to _sort_by
_sort_by is faster than _sort by 2x ± 1.0

bench_em 100_000
arr contains 100000 elements
Running each test once. Test will take about 3 seconds.
_sort_by_with_hash is similar to _values_at
_values_at is similar to _sort_by
_sort_by is faster than _sort by 2x ± 0.1
```

Comment: Cary, so sorry I didn't catch this yesterday.  I was so glad to have a solution that I didn't follow up.   This is really good analysis and my `@bible` array (or whatever it will be called) is quite large.  If I get this thing off the ground, I may very well be comparing performance and use your solution in my final code.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

As can be seen from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-index), `Array#index` indeed does work for strings (it's even the provided example), so this would work:

```
books.sort_by { |b| array.index(b[:book]) }
```

But instead of repeatedly searching through `array`, you can just determine the order once and then look it up:

```
order = array.each.with_index.to_h
#=> { "Matthew" => 0, "Mark" => 1, "Acts" => 2, "1John" => 3 }
books.sort_by { |b| order[b[:book]] }
```

Comment: I somehow missed your answer earlier. I expected the hash to speed up `sort_by` quite a lot, but my benchmarks suggest that it doesn't.

Comment: The array is probably too small for that to make a noticeable difference. But for larger arrays I'd certainly use this approach.

Comment: Ah, I missed your update with all the BM results above. Seems like even for biggish arrays the difference between my and your solution is negligible. Maybe the implementation of `sort_by` with a two element array offsets the benefit of using a hash for generating the external order, so I'd say one should use whatever code makes semantically the most sense. Thanks for the benchmarks!

Comment: Apologies Michael, I am just seeing this now.  Thank you so much for taking the time to put this together.  This is definitely a more readable solution and I have upvoted it.  It is nice to understand how the backend sorting works but I will definitely go this route in the future.

Comment: @KurtW Don't worry, it seems that you learned a lot from this answer and that's what SO is about.

Comment: Thanks Michael :) -- hey, does Ruby 2.0.0 not support the `.to_h` method on `Enumerator`?    Just specifying `order = nt_books.each.with_index.to_h` gives me `undefined method  'to_h' for #<Enumerator:0x00000000640168>'`.   If Ruby 2.0.0 doesn't support it, what is the alternative for legacy versions of Ruby?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're right, `to_h` was added in 2.1.0. The Alternative in this case is `Hash[nt_books.each.with_index.to_h]`.

Answer (score 2):

As the description of `Array#sort_by` accepts a block. The block should return -1, 0, or +1 depending on the comparison between a and b. You can use `find_index` on the `array` to do such comparison.

`array_of_hashes.sort_by {|a| array.find_index(a[:book]) }` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your time Chaitanya!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to think that you are sorting. But, in fact, you are not, you already have the order, you just need to place the elements. I'm not proposing a compact or optimal solution, but a simple solution. First convert your large array into a hash indexed by the `:book` key (which should have been your first data structure), and then just use `map`:

```
array = ['Matthew', 'Mark', 'Acts', '1John']
elements = [{:book=>"Matthew",
  :chapter=>"4",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"Matthew",
  :chapter=>"22",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"Mark",
  :chapter=>"6",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"1John",
  :chapter=>"1",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"1John",
  :chapter=>"1",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"Acts",
  :chapter=>"9",
  :section=>"new_testament"},
 {:book=>"Acts",
  :chapter=>"17",
  :section=>"new_testament"}]
by_name = {}
for e in elements
  by_name[e[:book]] = e
end
final = array.map { |x| by_name[x] }
```

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't see there were more than one entry with the same name, forget this.