# Rails loop over hash in custom order conditionally

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I'm working on a RoR web application.

I have to loop over an array of hashes in a custom order based on the value of the hash.

In this example, the "Pending" status needs to appear first in the list.

Is it possible to customize the order of the array in the each loop?

```
<% example_statuses = [{ :status => "Active", :job_count => 0 }, { :status => "Pending", :job_count => 1 }, { :status => "Complete", :job_count => 3 }] %>
<% example_statuses.each do |es| %>
  <h3><%= es[:status] %></h3>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:
I have a simple working example that involves removing and prepending the pending status hash back into the array. HOWEVER is there a way to create a custom order instead of manually replacing values one by one?

```
<% example_statuses = [{ :status => "Active", :job_count => 0 }, { :status => "Pending", :job_count => 1 }, { :status => "Complete", :job_count => 3 }] %>
<%= pending = example_statuses.find { |x| x[:status] == "Pending"} %>
<% example_statuses.delete(pending) %>
<% example_statuses.prepend(pending) %>
<% example_statuses.each do |es| %>
  <h3><%= es[:status] %></h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: if you want a semi-deterministic (pending first, f the rest) outcome at every execution, just store that order and render it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two important concepts here:

1. Using `Array#index` to find where in an array an element is found.
2. The 'spaceship operator' `<=>` which is how `Array#sort` works. You can investigate it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator)

In your case solution would be:

```
example_statuses = [{ :status => "Active", :job_count => 0 }, { :status => "Pending", :job_count => 1 }, { :status => "Complete", :job_count => 3 }]

order = ["Pending", "Active", "Complete"]

sorted_array = example_statuses.sort do |a,b|
  order.index(a[:status]) <=> order.index(b[:status])
end
# => [{:status=>"Pending", :job_count=>1}, {:status=>"Active", :job_count=>0}, {:status=>"Complete", :job_count=>3}]
```

Comment: i found the solution inside similar to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121932/ruby-sort-array-of-hashes-values-string-based-on-array-order). If you wanna go a bit deeper check all the answers provided.

Comment: `sorted_array = example_statuses.sort_by{|es| order.index(es[:status]) }` is more concise -  and does not involve the inner workings of sorting.

Comment: That spaceship operator question looks familiar...

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with single line like this `example_statuses.sort_by{|x| x[:status] == 'Pending' ? '' : x[:status] }`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are given an array `order` that can be reordered to equal

```
example_statuses.map { |h| h[:status] }
  #=> ["Active", "Pending", "Complete"]
```

and that you wish to sort `example_statuses` to produce an array `sorted` such that

```
sorted.map { |h| h[:status] } == order
  #=> true
```

You do not need to actually sort `example_statues`, which would have a computational complexity of O(`n*log(n)`) where `n` equals the number of elements in `example_statuses`.

Instead, do the following, which has a computational complexity close to O(`n`). Suppose

```
order = ["Pending", "Active", "Complete"]
```

**Case 1: `g[:status] != h[:status]` for all pairs of distinct elements `g` and `h` of `example_statuses`**

In this case compute

```
example_statuses.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:status]] = g }
                .values_at(*order)
  #=> [{:status=>"Pending", :job_count=>1},
  #    {:status=>"Active", :job_count=>0},
  #    {:status=>"Complete", :job_count=>3}]
```

The receiver of [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) is seen to be the following.

```
example_statuses.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:status]] = g }
  #=> {"Active"=>{:status=>"Active", :job_count=>0},
  #    "Pending"=>{:status=>"Pending", :job_count=>1},
  #    "Complete"=>{:status=>"Complete", :job_count=>3}}
```

---

I earlier claimed that the computational complexity was "almost" O(`n`). Building the hash `example_statuses.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:status]] = g }` is O(`n`) but the key lookup for each element or `order` is only "almost" O(1). Were is a constant time the complexity would be O(`n`).

**Case 2: `g[:status] == h[:status]` for at least one pair of distinct elements `g` and `h` of `example_statuses`**

Of course this case may not be permitted but that has not been made clear by the question.

Suppose `order` is as before but `example_statuses` is as follows.

```
example_statuses = [
  { :status => "Active", :job_count => 0 },
  { :status => "Pending", :job_count => 1},
  { :status => "Complete", :job_count => 3 },
  { :status => "Active", :job_count => 7 }
]
```

Note that `example_statuses[0][:status]` and `example_statuses[3][:status]` both equal `"Active"`.

We need just a slight modification of the Case 1 calculation (which does not affect computational complexity).

```
example_statuses.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h| 
  h[g[:status]] << g
end.values_at(*order).flatten
  #=> [{:status=>"Pending", :job_count=>1},
  #    {:status=>"Active", :job_count=>0},
  #    {:status=>"Active", :job_count=>7},
  #    {:status=>"Complete", :job_count=>3}]
```

The receivers of `values_at` is seen to equal the following.

```
{"Active"=>[{:status=>"Active", :job_count=>0},
            {:status=>"Active", :job_count=>7}],
 "Pending"=>[{:status=>"Pending", :job_count=>1}],
 "Complete"=>[{:status=>"Complete", :job_count=>3}]}
```

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block and no argument. When `h` does not have a key `[g[:status]` this causes `h[g[:status]]` to be assigned to an empty array before executing `g[:status]<< g`.